# GTK progress bar with 2 levels

Tags: gtk, progress-bar

I would like to have a progress bar in GTK (3.24, in linux) that shows 2 different levels on the same bar.
I searched the documentation but I could not find anything that could help me, I hope someone here can.

For example one level would be the transfered size of a file and the other level the processed size. Ofcourse, the 2 different levels shown on the same bar would be with different colours.
How could I accomplish this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to write your own custom progress bar that does what you want. (Luckily, you can probably inherit from, or even copy, the regular `GtkProgressBar`.)

Comment: Yeah, thought so! I tried to avoid building custom widgets, but I guess there's no way around it if I want certain things. Standard widgets cannot cover every need. Thanks!